# How to match more than one property of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can match a single property easy enough

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

$.each(peoples, function(i, val) {
    $.each(val, function(key, name) {
        if (name === "john")
            console.log(key + " : " + name);
       });
});
```

But since there are 2 johns how do I match a particular one (eg the john that like sushi) and then return the whole matched object (in json)? I tried adding another condition to the if statement but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check exact match

```js
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

var filteredResult = peoples.find(val => val.name ==="john" && val.dinner==="sushi");
console.log(filteredResult)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I was trying to avoid using .find() as I believe it is not compatible with Internet explorer

Comment: oh, it not mentioned that you need for IE, then you can try like this. const output = {}; 
`$.each(peoples, function(i, val) {
  if (val.name == "john" && val.dinner == "sushi") {
    output = val;
  }
});`

Comment: Thanks. That works great and returns the object too :)

Comment: if you get the answer as expected thats great.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
var peoples = [{
    "name": "bob",
    "dinner": "pizza"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "dinner": "sushi"
  },
  {
    "name": "larry",
    "dinner": "hummus"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "dinner": "pie"
  }
];

$.each(peoples, function(i, val) {
  if (val.name == "john" && val.dinner == "sushi") {
    console.log("Persons[" + i + "]." + Object.keys(val)[0] + ": " + val.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This iterates all the items and compares elements of each.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context, but there could be two john and both with the dinner property set to pie. I would suggest using id for each entry in the array. If the array you are working with is the one you list, you could project/transform it using `map` before you perform searches. For example

```js
const people = [
  { name: "bob", dinner: "pizza" },
  { name: "john", dinner: "sushi" },
  { name: "larry", dinner: "hummus" },
  { name: "john", dinner: "pie" },
];

const peopleList = people.map((person, id) => ({ id, ...person }));

console.log(peopleList);

// You could start from here to search by id
```

Comment: Thanks. That's really useful to know and may come in handy

Answer (score 1):

### _.filter by lodash

You can use *filter* method by lodash
Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for.The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).It return a new array

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter

**Example for filter usage on lodash**

```js
var users = [{
    'user': 'barney',
    'age': 36,
    'active': true
  },
  {
    'user': 'fred',
    'age': 40,
    'active': false
  },
  {
    'user': 'fred',
    'age': 39,
    'active': true
  }
];

console.log("matches:", _.filter(users, function(o) {
  return !o.active;
}));
// => [{ active: true, age: 36, user: "barney"}]

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
console.log("_.matches` iteratee", _.filter(users, {
  'user': 'fred',
  'active': true
}));
// => [{ active: true, age: 39, user: "fred"}]

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
console.log("matchs poperty", _.filter(users, ['active', false]));
// => objects for ['fred']

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, 'active');
// => objects for ['barney']
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### _.where by underscore.js

You can also use *where* method of underscore.js
Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that
matches the key-value pairs listed in properties.
`_.where(list, properties)`

Example of _.where usage
`_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});`

### You can basicaly use filter method in plain vanilla javascript

```js
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

var dinner = peoples.filter(e=>e.name ==="john" && e.dinner==="sushi");

console.log(dinner)
```

### You may also use jquery grep

```js
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

var dinner = $.grep(peoples, function(people) {
    return people.name === "john" && people.dinner === "sushi";
});

console.log(dinner)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Find vs filter

```js
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

var filterDinner = peoples.filter(e=>e.name ==="john" && e.dinner==="sushi");

// return all matching results
console.log('filter dinner -:', filterDinner);

var findDinner = peoples.find(e=>e.name ==="john" && e.dinner==="sushi");

//returns the first matching rslt
console.log('find dinner -:', findDinner);
```

Find was not recommended because it return the first matching result and suppose we have more matching results they are missed out.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. There are plenty of options here.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a function to define your search terms then use `Array.filter`:

```
const peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "pie" }
];

searchTerms = (person) => {
  return person.name === "john" && person.dinner === "sushi";
}

console.log(peoples.filter(searchTerms));

// [{ "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" }]
```